# Telerik RadComboBox WPF How to display list of values from database table?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

I'm using MVVM with WPF and have a RadComboBox in my view that needs to be populated from my County table in my database.  My viewmodel is as follows:

```
 public class AddClientViewModel : BindableBase
 {
    private Client _client;
    private Circuit _circuit;
    private County _county;
    private State _state;
    private SubscriberSpecialty _subscriberSpecialty;
    private IClientsRepository _repository = new ClientRepository();
    private ICircuitRepository _circuitRepository = new CircuitRepository();
    private ICountyRepository _countyRepository = new CountyRepository();
    private IStateRepository _stateRepository = new StateRepository();
    private ISubscriberSpecialty _subscriberSpecialtyRepository = new SubscriberSpecialtyRepository();

    public AddClientViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSave);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public Client Client
    {
        get { return _client; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _client)
            {
                _client = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new  PropertyChangedEventArgs("Client"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Circuit Circuit
    {
        get { return _circuit; }
        set
        {
            if(value != _circuit)
            {
                _circuit = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Circuit"));
            }
        }
    }

    public County County
    {
        get { return _county;}
        set
        {
            if (value != _county)
            {
                _county = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("County"));
            }
        }
    }

    public State State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _state)
            {
                _state = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("State"));
            }
        }
    }

    public SubscriberSpecialty SubscriberSpecialty
    {
        get { return _subscriberSpecialty; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _subscriberSpecialty)
            {
                _subscriberSpecialty = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SubscriberSpecialty"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Guid ClientId { get; set; }
    public Guid CircuitId { get; set; }
    public Guid CountyId { get; set; }
    public Guid StateId { get; set; }
    public Guid SubscriberSpecialtyId { get; set; }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

    public event Action<Client> AddClient = delegate { };

    public async void LoadClient()
    {
        Client = await _repository.GetClientAsync(ClientId);
    }

    public async void LoadCircuit()
    {
        Circuit = await _circuitRepository.GetCircuitAsync(CircuitId);
    }

    public async void LoadCounty()
    {
        County = await _countyRepository.GetCountyAsync(CountyId);
    }

    public async void LoadState()
    {
        State = await _stateRepository.GetStateAsync(StateId);
    }

    public async void LoadSubscriberSpecialty()
    {
        SubscriberSpecialty = await _subscriberSpecialtyRepository.GetSubscriberSpecialtyAsync(SubscriberSpecialtyId);
    }

    private void OnAddClient()
    {
        AddClient(new Client {ClientId = Guid.NewGuid()});
    }

    private async void OnSave()
    {
        try
        {
            Client = await _repository.AddClientAsync(new Client());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A handled exception just occurred: " + ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK,
                MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
    }
}
```

The interface has the following:

```
Task<County> GetCountyAsync(Guid countyId);
```

The repository class calls the interface as:

```
public Task<List<County>> GetCountiesAsync()
{
    return _context.Counties.ToListAsync();
}
```

My view then uses the following syntax:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="Countycombo" 
 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding County.CountyName}" 
 DisplayMemberPath="CountyName" Width="120"/>
```

I defined a DataContext in the layout as follows:

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModels:AddClientViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

When I run the application, the RadComboBox doesn't grab the values from the County table, into which I've loaded several values for CountyName.  How do I correct the above code snippets to ensure my County Names are populated?

**Update**:  When I remove County from County.CountyName, I receive the message stating `Cannot resolve property CountyName in DataContext MySolution.ViewModels.MyViewModel`  What additional work is needed in the viewmodel either in LoadCounty or other sections?

Comment: Remove `.CountyName` from `ItemsSource="{Binding County.CountyName}"`

Comment: Thanks.  Please see update as further guidance is needed.

Comment: Whats the name of the ViewModel property that holds a list of County objects? Where do you store the result of GetCountiesAsync?

Comment: In `ItemsSource` you have a bind a collection of objects (probably the result of `GetCountiesAsync()`. `DisplayMemberPath` indicates which property of each item in your list should be displayed (eg. CountyName, or CountyId, etc.)

Comment: @jure I might not have setup the viewmodel to do this just yet.  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

Introduce the ViewModel property that will hold a list of `County` objects:

```
private List<County> _counties;
public List<County> Counties
{
    get { return _counties;}
    set
    {
        if (value != _counties)
        {
            _counties = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Counties"));
        }
    }
}
```

Bind a ComboBox `ItemsSource` to the Counties property, and a ComboBox `SelectedItem` property to the County property.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="Countycombo" 
 Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Counties}" 
 SelectedItem="{Binding County}"
 DisplayMemberPath="CountyName" Width="120"/>
```

And you need to a place where you will load the counties with a repository call to a `GetCountiesAsync`. The result should be set to the ViewModel Counties property.

```
  public async void LoadCounties()
  {
     Counties = await _countyRepository.GetCountiesAsync();
  }
```

Not sure what is the best place to make that call.